# What would be a good icon for voiding and unvoiding a worksheet?

Tags: user-interface, icons

In our application we have an option to void and unvoid a worksheet(make it so it doesn't matter for reporting, etc). What would be a good icon to represent this action?

Comment: To whoever is voting to close this as belongs on Super User, I suggest reading the question before voting to close. This is a Stack Overflow question about the understandability of icons. It belongs here.

Comment: Not sure why people think this belongs on superuser. I could see belongs on doctype though...

Comment: while its not the right place to ask this question, but here you go: http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/17/top-10-icon-search-engines-and-libraries/ you ask this type of question on http://doctype.com

Comment: @Amr strangely enough, none of those sites had a relevant void icon.

Comment: I agree that this is more about creating usable software than it is about using existing software.  Cleared the votes to migrate to SU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Void: A ghost-like (faded) version of the worksheet icon (if you already have one)
- Unvoid: A solid version of the worksheet icon

They'll imply that void worksheets are passed over during reporting but still exist.

Maybe the icons should have an action, like arrows depicting that the solid version becomes the ghost-like version for the "void" icon and the opposite for the "unvoid" icon.

---

In any case, I advise you to make up several sets of icons and present them to your users inside the application during usability testing to verify which set is the most understandable.

Comment: For right now I did the "ghost like" thing.. you're right though, it'd be very nice to have an animation for this..

Comment: In testing be sure to check if users will confused a ghosted icon with being a disabled toolbar control. Then there's the question on if the icon represents the current state or the state the user gets on activation.

Answer (score 1):

Void rubber stamp.

Comment: What about the unvoiding though?

Comment: @Earlz: If the icon is a toggle, the look of the void rubber stamp being pressed in would be the unvoid button. That is if you have toggle buttons elsewhere. Might be confusing to have just one toggle button in the entire app.

Answer (score 1):

Use a checkbox with the label "include in reports" or similar.

I can't speak to your overall design (since I've not seen it), but [icons often hurt usability](http://uxmyths.com/post/715009009/myth-icons-enhance-usability) while a checkbox should be much more easily understood.  This does not strike me as a feature that will be used often, and therefore does not need the space savings an icon provides because it doesn't need to always be shown.